# Django ModelForm: Defining a value not passed into the template

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a ModelForm, and I want to only pass *some* of the fields into the template. I would like to save one particular field to define after the POST request has been sent. Here is the ModelForm:

```
class CreateListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ListingModel
        fields = ['name', 'image', 'description', 'price', 'category']
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea()
        }
```

And here is the Model:

```
class ListingModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    objects = models.Manager()
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In the next code block, I am attempting to define the `owner` field according to the current user logged in (`request.user.username`):

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name=login_view)
def create_listing(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "auctions/createlisting.html", {
            "CreateListingForm": forms.CreateListingForm()
        })
    
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.CreateListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            try:
                form.owner = request.user.username
                print(form.owner)
                form.save(commit=True)
            except Exception:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create_listing_error"))

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index")) #TODO
```

Now, when I say `print(form.owner)`, the result is correct. However when I save the ModelForm, the owner field is left blank. Am I not defining the value of the `owner` field correctly?

Comment: form.save(commit=True) will save only fields that you have already defined in the meta class.

Comment: if you want to save extra field after POST call you should use different approach. One potential approach can be to use post_save signal for ListingModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* confuse the `ModelForm` with the instance it is wrapping. The fact that it prints something for `form.owner` is not that strange, you first *set* an attribute named `.owner`, an attribute that did not exists *before*. You should set the `.owner` of the **`.instance` of the form**:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name=login_view)
def create_listing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.owner = request.user.username
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateListingForm()
    return render(request, 'auctions/createlisting.html', {
        'CreateListingForm': form
    })
```

Where *`'name-of-some-view'`* should be replaced by the name of some view to which you redirect in case the form was valid.

You should however consider changing the `CharField` of `owner` to a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). Imagine that later the user changes their `username`, then your `ListingModel`s do no longer refer to a real user.

Comment: Your solution worked. I just implemented it. Thank you!